# Vauxhall Astra intermittent engine problem

Tags: engine, gasoline

I have a 2015 Vauxhall Astra (petrol) with a strange intermittent problem, hoping someone might have experienced something similar.

The car lost power and stalled after driving perfectly normally. It would not re-start.
After about 2 hours, it started and drove normally for about 40 miles over 2 days - then did exactly the same thing again.

Mechanic found no codes, but suspected various sensors and changed them all.

He has left the car running (idling) for up to 5 hours. Sometimes it then drives normally, others it stops when you try to drive it. So it seems like it might be temperature related.

In response to a similar question on this site, an answer suggested the fuel pump binding when at temperature. This is possible, but I find it unlikely, only because I saw the petrol gushing from the pipe when turning over and the car would not start.

Mechanic is currently suggesting ECU fault - which seems unlikely to me, and will also be an expensive replacement.

Any suggestions or things that are worth considering please?

Comment: Down vote
It would help if you listed the sensors that were replaced. A failing crankcase position sensor can do this. But maybe that's been replaced?

Comment: @Jupiter I'm not entirely sure what sensors were replaced, but if you could provide an answer or a comment with a list of sensors that might cause this behaviour, that would be very helpful.

Comment: petrol gushing from what pipe?

Comment: @RoryAlsop The mechanic disconnected the fuel supply pipe from the manifold and got me to turn it over. Fuel  gushed out of the pipe. He then reconnected the pipe and got me to try it again - nothing.

Comment: A faulty crankshaft position sensor could cause it to act like you are describing and it may not throw a code.

Comment: @Jupiter I have a feeling that is one of the ones he changed, but I will ask. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jupiter Yes, apparently he has changed the crankshaft sensor THREE times, he was so convinced that must be the cause of the problem.